# deserialization issue with char '\'

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Does json.net have an in built method that would escape special characters? My json strings I recv from vendors have `\`, double `"` .

If not what is the best way to escape the special charecters before invoking `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myjsonString)`?

My sample json string

```
{
    "EmailAddresses": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "N\A"

        }
    ]
}
```

Pasting this in json lint results in 
`Parse error on line 4:
...    "EmailAddress": "N\A",

-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['`

VB.NET code

```
instanceofmytype = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of myType)(myJsonString)
```

Exception:  `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Bad JSON escape sequence:`

Comment: What happens if you wrap the example input with curly braces? `"{" + json + "}"`

Comment: also try putting in 2 `\`.

Comment: Your sample is not JSON (missing outer `{...}`)... Please show complete C# sample code that demonstrates the problem - there is a good chance that you simply doing something wrong - valid JSON can have as many `\` and `"` properly encoded...

Comment: How are you forming your JSON? You should use a good JSON library, like Json.NET (for .NET) or jQuery (for JS). If you *really* have to write it yourself, be sure to follow all [the rules of the specification](http://www.json.org/) so that your JSON can be read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is not valid: a `\` must be followed by one of the following: `"\/bfnrtu`. Since it's followed by `A`, Json.NET chokes (as it ought to). The source of your JSON should be fixed. If this is not an option, you can make a guess to fix it yourself, e.g.

```
myStr = Regex.Replace(myStr, "\\(?=[^""\\/bfnrtu])", "\\")
```

Comment: I will need to escape all special charecters, correct? my json can contain `\`, `/`,`'`,`"`, `#`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about it. JSON.NET handles a lot of nice things for you. It should just work.

Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have. I edited my ? with more detail and exception I have